# Why does the counter variable come up one short for words?

Tags: c, cs50, c-strings, counting, function-definition

The word count always comes up one short. I tried adding +1 - +10 on `i < len;` I've tried removing the space after "Text: " in the `get_string` prompt. For example, the prompt entry "One fish. Two fish. Red fish. Blue fish." compiles and the output for letters is correct, 29 letters, the output for words is **WRONG** (off by 1) — 7 words (**should be 8**), and the output for sentences is correct as well — 4 sentences. I'm assuming the `isblank` inside the prototype `int count_words(string sample)` doesn't count the last word because the last word ends with a period.

Is setting the counter to 1 instead of 0 a good idea or is there a better way to get the last word?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_letters(string sample);
int count_words(string sample);
int count_sentences(string sample);

int main(void)
{
    string sample = get_string("Text: ");
    printf("%s\n", sample);

    int lettercount = count_letters(sample);
    printf("%i letters\n", lettercount);

    int wordcount = count_words(sample);
    printf("%i words\n", wordcount);

    int sentencescount = count_sentences(sample);
    printf("%i sentences\n", sentencescount);
}

int count_letters(string sample)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int len = strlen(sample);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(sample[i]))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

int count_words(string sample)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int len = strlen(sample);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isblank(sample[i]))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

int count_sentences(string sample)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int len = strlen(sample);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if ((sample[i] == '.') || (sample[i] == '?') || (sample[i] == '!'))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: You only count blanks. But there's no blank after the last word.

Comment: This sentence has four blanks.  And five words.

Comment: Initialising the counter with 1 may cause problems when your input has no words (i.e. empty string).

Comment: What happens if there are several consecutive blanks?  What happens if there are one or more blanks at the start, or one or more blanks at the end?  You need to keep track of an 'in word' status, which is true when the last character was part of a word and is set to false when you find an inter-word gap (a blank).  Would you be better served by counting when you find the start of a word, rather than by when you find an inter-word character?  (Is the sentence count OK for an input like "`You said what?!!?`"?

Answer (score 3):

> Is setting the counter to 1 instead of 0 a good idea ...

Setting the counter to 1 is bad as the string may have zero words.

OP's approach does not work in all cases where the strings may optionally begin/end with non-letters.

- Best to use `unsigned char` values for `is...()` functions as those functions are not defined for most negative values.
- A very *long* string may exceed length `INT_MAX`.  Best to count letters/words with `size_t` to handle all strings.
- Rather than iterate to the length of the string, iterate until reading a *null character*. This skips the unnecessary (and expensive) prior `strlen()` call.

> ... or is there a better way to get the last word?

A simple ways to count words:  **Count transitions from non-letter to letter**.
Less complex and less error prone than many other approaches.

```
size_t count_words(const char *str) {
  const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char*) str;
  size_t words = 0;
  bool previous_is_letter = false;

  while (*us) {
    bool current_is_letter = isalpha(*us++);
    if (!previous_is_letter && current_is_letter) words++;
    previous_is_letter = current_is_letter;
  }

  return words;
}
```

---

Counting letters only needs 1 pass down the string, not 2, like OP's code.

- `is...()` functions return 0 or non-zero.  Use `!!` to convert any non-zero value to 1.

```
size_t count_letters(const char *str) {
  size_t letters = 0;
  const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char*) str;
  while (*us) {
    letters += !!isalpha(*us);
    us++;
  }
  return letters;
}
```

Counting sentences is similar.

```
// letters += !!isalpha(*us);
sentences += *us == '.' || *us == '?' || *us == '!';
```

Comment: I like it, nice addition to a well answered question. Learning can certainly occur on this one.

Comment: For consistency, you could also write `words += (current_is_letter && !previous_is_letter);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the OP code presumes single spaces between words, and does not account for the absence of a space at the end of the string.

Without making a copy or reinventing standard library functions, the following seems to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int cntWords( char *str ) {
    int cnt = 0;

    str += strspn( str, " " );  // discard leading spaces
    while( *str ) {
        cnt++;
        str += strcspn( str, " " ); // find next SP
        str += strspn( str, " " ); // find next that is not SP
    }

    return cnt;
}

int main( void ) {
    printf( "words = %d\n", cntWords( "One fish Two fish Red Fish Blue Fish" ) );
    printf( "words = %d\n", cntWords( "  One fish Two fish Red Fish Blue Fish" ) );
    printf( "words = %d\n", cntWords( "One fish Two fish Red Fish Blue Fish   " ) );
    printf( "words = %d\n", cntWords( "  One fish Two fish Red Fish Blue Fish " ) );

    return 0;
}
```

```
words = 8
words = 8
words = 8
words = 8
```

---

**EDIT**
The function can be made even more compact:

```
int cntWords( char *str ) {
    int cnt = 0;

    while( *str ) {
        str += strspn( str, " " );  // find next non-space
        cnt += *str != '\0';
        str += strcspn( str, " " ); // find next space
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `count_words()` function you do not account properly for the presence or absence of leading whitespace, multiple included whitespace characters and trailing whitespace. Essentially you are treating each space as a word.

While you can handle this with library functions (@Fe203 using `scrcspn()`/`strspn()` is a good example), using a simple loop *State-Variable* where you keep track of whether you in a word reading characters or outside a word reading whitespace is another method that is quite efficient (and also operates on string-literals/constant string just fine.) Keeping track of the state of things is applicable to many many problems.

For your word count, you could do something as simple as the following, using `in_word` as your state-variable that keeps track of whether you are in a word reading characters or before, between or after a word reading whitespace, e.g.

```c
/* returns the number of whitespace separated words in str */
size_t count_words (const char *str)
{
    size_t words = 0;
    int in_word = 0;

    while (*str) {
        if (isspace ((unsigned char)*str))
            in_word = 0;
        else {
            if (!in_word)
                words++;
            in_word = 1;
        }
        str++;
    }

    return words;
}
```

(**note:** the word count `words` is only incremented on transition from not in-word to in-word, triggered on the first character in each word)

Shamelessly borrowing the example from @Fe203 with a few additional whitespace characters and breaking the string into two parts could be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* returns the number of whitespace separated words in str */
size_t count_words (const char *str)
{
    size_t words = 0;
    int in_word = 0;

    while (*str) {
        if (isspace ((unsigned char)*str))
            in_word = 0;
        else {
            if (!in_word)
                words++;
            in_word = 1;
        }
        str++;
    }

    return words;
}

int main (void) {
    
    printf ("words = %zu\n", count_words ( "One fish Two   fish Red Fish Blue Fish" ) );
    printf ("words = %zu\n", count_words ( "  One fish Two fish Red Fish Blue Fish" ) );
    printf ("words = %zu\n", count_words ( "One fish Two fish Red Fish Blue Fish   " ) );
    printf ("words = %zu\n", count_words ( "  One fish Two fish "
                                           "Red Fish Blue Fish " ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The result is the same, `8` words per string. Look it over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Invoice is in the mail... `:-)`... Nice solution. Clean, too! UV...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - not sure I follow. `if (!isspace(*((unsigned char *)str)) && *str) words++;` would count characters if that was the body of the `while()` loop?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, my alternate code was amiss.  Posted alternate code below.

Answer (score 1):

The function `count_words` does not take into account the last word because neither space followed it.

Also in general the function will count words incorrectly if between words there are more than one space character or if the string contains leading or trailing spaces.

And using the function `strlen` is inefficient and redundant.

The function can be defined the following way.

```
int count_words( string sample )
{
    int counter = 0;

    while ( *sample )
    {
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*sample ) ) ++sample;

        if ( *sample )
        {
            ++counter;
            while ( *sample && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*sample ) ) ++sample;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Though it would be much better to declare the function like

```
size_t count_words( const char *sample )
{
    size_t counter = 0;

    while ( *sample )
    {
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*sample ) ) ++sample;

        if ( *sample )
        {
            ++counter;
            while ( *sample && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*sample ) ) ++sample;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t count_words( const char *sample )
{
    size_t counter = 0;

    while (*sample)
    {
        while (isblank( ( unsigned char )*sample )) ++sample;

        if (*sample)
        {
            ++counter;
            while (*sample && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*sample )) ++sample;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *sample = "One fish. Two fish. Red fish. Blue fish.";

    printf( "There are %zu words.\n", count_words( sample ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
There are 8 words.
```

The function `count_sentences` is also incorrect. For example for this string `"What?!"` the function returns two sentences instead of one.

The function could be implemented the same way as the shown above  function `count_words`.

Answer (score -1):

This could work, maybe start the counter at 1, and return 0 if len equals zero? You are counting spaces, not words. so for the string "Hello World" you would count 1 because there's 1 space.

```
int count_words(string sample)
{
    int counter = 1;
    int len = strlen(sample);
    if(len == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isblank(sample[i]))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I would do it using strtok, really for no other reason than it counts the actual words for me, it's actually more complicated.

```
int count_words(const char *sample)
{
    char *cpy = NULL;
    char *token = NULL;
    int word_count = 0;

    /* I believe strtok will mangle the string so I'll make a copy of it */
    cpy = calloc(1, strlen(sample) + 1);
    if(!cpy) {
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(cpy, sample);

    token = strtok(cpy, " \t");
    while(token) {
        word_count++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }
    free(cpy);
    return word_count;
}
```

Comment: For your first fragment: What happens if there are several consecutive blanks? What happens if there are one or more blanks at the start, or if there are one or more blanks at the end?  (These are questions I asked in a comment to the question, but they're also relevant to your answer.)

Comment: You say (in a comment in the code) "I believe strtok() will mangle the string".  It will indeed mangle the string; making a copy of it is a good idea.  You could enforce that by making the argument `const char *sample`; then you couldn't use `strtok()` on the original argument.  Making strings that won't be changed constant is a good idea, in general.  Similar comments would apply to the other count functions.  This is, however, a refinement; the basic idea you show is correct.  Using `strtok()` deals with the leading, trailing and multiple blanks.

Comment: You might care to note that the `isblank()` function matches space `' '` and tab `'\t'`; you can fix that easily in your calls to `strtok()`.

Comment: @TWitvliet I like your answer. You showed how the function shall not be written.:) I am sure it is a very useful example for such beginners as me and the author of the question.

Comment: Rather than counting blanks count the times you encounter a letter following a non-letter. This will require you to keep track of the current character and the previous character. Initialize the previous character to a non-letter such as a blank so that you count the first word if the string begins with a letter.